# How to grant an Apps Script Web App authorization to access Google Sheets for all users in a domain using a service account

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I have a Google site that is viewed by hundreds of people a day within my domain.

I have embedded many Google script web apps into this which access a spreadsheet and display the data in as an HTML output.

My problem is that running the scripts as me will not be able to handle hundreds of concurrent users accessing it due to Google's simultaneous quota invocations.

I cannot run the scripts as the users because I would rather all of them not have to manually authorize every script.

We have created a service account with access to the Sheets API.
I need assistance in using the service account to authorize all the scripts for all users in the domain.

Here is the script web app I need to authorize:

```
function doGet()
{
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name).getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  value = CreateHtml(value);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(value);
}
```

Code I found online, I'm unsure of how to adapt this to solve my problem.
I already have a JSON with the relevant keys and user info but I have no idea what the property store, params or scopes should be

```
function getOAuthService() 
{
    return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
        .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')
        .setPrivateKey(JSON.private_key)
        .setIssuer(JSON.client_email)
        .setSubject(JSON.user_email)
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
        .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
        .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}
```

Thus code is from the same site as the code above. I don't know if I need to do anything with it or not.

```
function getUserFiles()
{
    var service = getOAuthService();
    Logger.log(service.hasAccess());
    if (service.hasAccess()) 
    {
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?pageSize=1'
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
            }
        });

    }
}

function reset() 
{
    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();
}
```